# Is it possible to have multiple App components in a Next.js application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In our next.js (v11) application we have a couple of different types of pages. Currently we have a custom `App` component to centralize elements valid for all pages. However I'd like to further minimize the overhead and define additional `App` components for the various types of pages.

Is it possible to have more than one `App` component and tell the framework which to use for a certain page?

If not, is there any other way to define something like a base page that other pages are derived from?

Comment: How do you identify the page types?

Comment: Why don't you use the `App` component itself for defining different logics?

Comment: @PsyGik Different parts of our application have different purposes. E.g. the main app always has a footer and header. White label pages on the other hand are stripped from all footers and headers.

Comment: @TaghiKhavari Yes, I thought about that possibility. Though it would be nicer to be able to derive pages from a "base page".

Comment: If it's the layouts you are after, Next.js docs has a dedicated section and examples on how to achieve that. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there's no way to have several base `App`s and derive pages from them. However as Taghi Khavari suggested, I will define the different base pages in the `App` component itself. It's not a perfect approach, but it works.